# Champernowne constant (Series of Integers) for C

Tags: c

I am prompted for a code to somehow print the series of Champernowne constant. (Actually work with it!)
so we want to find the n-th digit of such series: 
`1234567891011121314...`
Here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

long long int num(long long int a);
long long int f(long long int n);
long long int power(long long int a, long long int b);
long long int dig(long long int a, long long int b);   

/*MAIN*/

int main(void) {
    long long int n = 0, k = 0, r = 0, m = 0;
    /* n , num(n) , primary       result , range specifier */
    scanf("%lld", &n);

    k = num(n);
    if (k <= 1) {
        printf("%lld\n", n);
    } else {
        for (m = 0; n > f(power(10, m) - 1); m++) {
        }

        r = n - f(power(10, m - 1) - 1);

        if (r % m == 0) {
            printf("%lld\n", dig(power(10, m - 1) - 1 + r / m, 1)); 
        } else {
            printf("%lld\n",
                   dig(power(10, m - 1) - 1 + (int)r / m + 1, m + 1 - (r % m)));
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}

/*How many digits do we have ? */

long long int num(long long int a) {
    long long int b = a;
    long long int c = 0;
    while (b != 0) {
        b /= 10;
        ++c;
    }
    return c;
}

/* Power */
long long int power(long long int a, long long int b) { 
    if (b == 0) {
        return 1L;
    }
    long long int c = 1;
    long long int d;
    d = a;
    for (c = 1; c < b; c = c + 1) { a = a * d; }
    return a;
}  

/* Lets solve it! */
long long int f(long long int n) {
    int k = num(n);
    if (k == 1) { return n; }
    return f(power(10, (k - 1)) - 1) + k * (n - (power(10, (k - 1)) - 1));
}

/*Digit */
long long int dig(long long int a, long long int b) {
    long long int x = 0, z = 0, t = 0;
    x = a % power(10, (b));
    z = power(10, (b - 1));
    t = x / z;
    return t;
}
```

But it has a gap I suppose, because it fails to pass 1 of the 7 test cases provided for it! Can anyone help me?

Comment: MSVC compiler at `int k = num(n);` gives warning " 'initializing': conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data." Oh and *please* learn how to format code with proper indentation and appropriate use of whitespace.

Comment: ... and use meaningful variable names. If that is boring to type all those letters, do a search/replace after you write the code.

Comment: I reformatted your code for readability, try and use this style.

Comment: I'm embarrassed ! Looks like i need to work on how to code cleaner first ! Any way thank u guys ! I don't think the K part is the problem because can an integer with number of digits grater than int capacity exist in c?

Comment: related? https://oeis.org/A033307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little too complicated, I did not locate the problem, but I suspect you should decrement `n` by `f(power(10, m) - 1)` in your initial loop.

Here is a simpler program that can be customized for different bases and used from the command line or standard input:

**champernowne.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int digit(long long int pos, int base) {
    int n = 1;            /* number of digits of the block numbers */
    long long power = 1;  /* power of base at the start of the block */

    if (pos <= 0)
        return 0;

    pos--;  /* adjust position such that 1st digit is 1 */
    for (;;) {
        /* length of the block of n-digit numbers */
        long long int block = power * (base - 1) * n;
        if (pos < block)
            break;
        pos -= block;
        power *= base;
        n++;
    }
    long long num = power + pos / n;
    for (pos %= n; pos < n - 1; pos++) {
        num /= base;
    }
    return (int)(num % base);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long long int n;
    if (argc > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", digit(strtoll(argv[i], NULL, 0), 10));
        }
    } else {
        while (scanf("%lld", &n) == 1) {
            printf("%d\n", digit(n, 10));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can use a simple benchmark:

```
chqrlie@mac ~/dev/stackoverflow > ./champernowne {1..10000} | tr -d '\n' > c10000
```

And verify that `c10000` contains the first 10000 digits of the Champernowne sequence.

You can also perform some verifications with the following programs:

**generator.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (long long n = 1;; n++)
        printf("%lld", n);
}
```

**extractor.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        long long i = 0, n = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 0);
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            if (++i == n) {
                printf("%c\n", c);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example:

```
chqrlie@mac ~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./generator | ./extractor 1000000000
1

real    0m46.741s
user    1m6.978s
sys     0m0.759s

chqrlie@mac ~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./champernowne 1000000000
1

real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Comment: Thank you ! Very helpful :) I just didn't get the benchmark part because i'm still an amateur  ! But as far as i understood , it won't be useful because test cases are much larger than 10000.

Comment: For example , what should i do if one of my test cases are 10000000000?

Comment: @BenFM: You can write a trivial program to generate the series on standard output pipe the output into another program that extracts the n-th digit. You should be able to run tests for positions into the billions in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Again i get the incorrect "-1" answer for n = 3000000000!

Comment: @BenFM: my code produces `5` for `3000000000` (3 billion) and the verification succeeds (after a painful 3 minutes of hard work)

Comment: @VerkhocevaKatya: there are no arrays in my version of **champernowne.c**

Comment: @VerkhocevaKatya: indeed `argv` is an array, but it is not used to solve the problem, merely to receive command line arguments. `main` receives a pointer to an array of C strings `argv`, along with the number of strings `argc`, from the OS. The first string is the name of the executing program, the following strings are the arguments given on the shell command line. In the example, the name of the program is `./champernowne` and there is a single argument `"1000000000"`, so `argc` is `2` and `argv[1]` points to `"1000000000"`, which `strtoll` will convert to the number `1000000000`.

Answer (score 0):

why even worry about guessing which digit it might be - just print it to full precision very quickly, without need for compilation
(this isn't exactly C, even though awk borrows heavily from that era).

I don't even know when the heck it'll even finish, but so far, only `01:hr:07:31secs` later, and it has already printed outs some **504-billion** digits of it, spanning some 469.8 GB uncompressed

```
-rw-r--r--  1 501  504,477,761,536 Mar 15 11:46:56 2022

            wioehnhoweoihwbhnboerbhwbhoebhohwebe.txt
```

You might notice how the code doesn't even attempt to perform any computations regarding the widths needed for each base-10 order of magnitude,

nor have any highly repetitive looping to increment the integer, with only exception being right at the starting point to create a 0-9 chain in string format.

- Using that starting chain of just all 10-digits, from 0 to 9 in
  ascending order, "`0123456789`", it performs
- 4 cycles of for loop in the first half of the pipeline,

  first 2 with 2-calls to global string regex
  substitution function `gsub()`,

  i.e. very similar to s/(…)/(…)/g in sed

  2 more cycles each with only 1 call to `gsub()`
- then 1 single call to `gsub()` per input row
  in 2nd half of pipeline
  after creating the regex replacement sentinel
  at the initiation process
- with a final instance of awk purely
  for formatting in order to alleviate pressure
  on the first 2

Because what the gsub() do is padding 2 more digits from 00 to 99 for all work done up to that point, and designed in such a fashion the numbers are already all pre-sorted in numerically ascending order, without any need to explicitly call a sorting utility. Big integer package/add-on isn't needed either.

Why do snail math when lightspeed string regex is available ?

```
  mawk2 'BEGIN { CONVFMT=OFMT="%.20g"; 

    for(____=__^=((_=(+_—)\
              (_+=int(9E-5^-2)))!=_)*gsub(".","|&",_);
           __<4;\
         __+=(-__<gsub("[|][^|]+",___,_))) { 

          if(+____) { ___=_;
                    gsub("[|]","\\&",___)
          if(__==2) { ____-=____ } 
 } }
 print _ }' \
 \
 | mawk2 'BEGIN { CONVFMT=OFMT="%.20g"; 
        
       for(____=__^=((_=(+_—)\
                (_+=int(9E-5^-2)))!=_)*gsub(".","|&",_);
             __<5;
           __+=(-__<gsub("[|][^|]+",___,_))) { 

          if(+____) { ___=_;
                    gsub("[|]","\\&",___)
          if(__==2) { ____-=____ } 
} }
    FS = RS = "["(OFS="|")"]";
                   ______=+"";
   ORS = (OFS)(ORS) 
} {                        __=_
   gsub("[|]","|"($______),__)
                     print __ 
}' \
| mawk2 'BEGIN {   FS = OFS = ORS
                          _^= ORS = ""
         printf("0.") 
     } {      gsub("[|]0*","")
         print 
 } END { 
        printf("\n") }'
```